# Which program can search and display multiple files, based on a list of file paths

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm trying to find a program that can:

- Import a list of file paths to search for
- Find and display specified files, in its own UI or Windows Explorer, so I can select and drag them onto another programs executable for further processing.

So far I've tried TreeSize Professional File Search, which offers somewhat similar functionality but requires each file path to be entered separately into search fields, which is not conventional in my case since I have several hundreds of files to process. I've also tried Total Commander, Altap Salamander, Ultra Search, File Boss, Disk Sorter..none of them has this ability.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing the search with [PowerGREP](https://www.powergrep.com/), then exporting the list of files and using [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851678.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to copy them.

Comment: It's worth noting there are several [free alternatives to PowerGREP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows). Not all of them have an export feature, but at least AstroGrep and BareGrep (and maybe others) do.